# Add shadow in linear layout when clicked and on long pressed like in buttons

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio

I was wondering if one can make linear layout to act like a button. I did allowed

```
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
```

everything is working fine except it doesn't have the main feature of a button , the Shadow which we get on a button when we click it or long press it. Please help me to solve it.

Answer (score 3):

Try setting this in LinearLayout background property, in your xml:

```
android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:
You can set state pressed of linear layout like button.

**button_state.xml**

```js
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    //background when pressed
    <item android:state_pressed="true" >
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:type="linear"
                android:startColor="#FFffffff"
                android:endColor="#FF000000"
                android:angle="45"/>
        </shape>

    </item>
    //Default background of linear
    <item>
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#1E669B"
                android:endColor="#1E669B"
                android:angle="270" />

        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

```js
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:id="@+id/linearlayout"
        android:background="@drawable/button_state"
        android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>
```

This is gradient generator
http://angrytools.com/gradient/

Comment: meos thanks for answering ... thats great but mate I have lil problem as i am a beginner ....in my linear layout I am already using a drawable background for outline of my layout now how should i contaminate this drawable to that one.

Comment: I don't understand your idea. You should post your layout.